# Unknown option removing background In render

Tags: rendering, texturing

Background material just showing as blank (Plane background with image texture on it) If I put a working material onto it, it still shows as blank, Its all checked in the top right, cant see what I've done, was trying to get a toon shader on and changed something following a tutorial.

When I render the vehicle looks exactly as I want it but I cant for the life of me get a new plane to show an image (UVMAP used and tried Coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different problems with your scene that are causing black materials.

- The ground for example is missing a shader. You have the image texture directly connected to the shader output, and there should be a shader in there, like a *Diffuse*, or *Glossy* or *Toon*.
- The glass color is a bit dark, though that may be the look you are aiming for.
- In the *Light Path* settings of the render panel you have all bounces set to zero, which will make most transparent or reflective materials return black

General tip, watch for the socket colors in the material node editor, under most circumstances connected socket colors should match (green with green, blue with blue, etc).